# IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to update the Firebase Bom from 31.5.0 to the latest 32.3.1, but I got this IllegalStateException when running the app again:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
> initialized in this process MyProcess. Make sure to call
> FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I understand this error occurs when we are not FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) or it did not succeed. It worked normally before so I am confused. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my code in Application:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    myApplication = this
    AdBlocker.init(this)
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
    MobileAds.initialize(this)
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(adConfig())
    checkInternetRunning()
}
```

App build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
// other ...
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'
```

Project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0' // google-services plugin

    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'org.jmailen.gradle:kotlinter-gradle:1.20.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

** Edit 1:

- targetSdkVersion = 34
- compileSdkVersion = 34